# Can OpenTBS be used to generate more than one invoices with a random number of order items?

Tags: php, mysql, opentbs

We succeeded in generating a single invoice with a random number of order items in a Word document with PHP and OpenTBS. But is it also possible to generate more than one invoices in one Word document? So an invoice per page containing a random number of order items.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge several invoices with a DOCX template using a block delimited on a page of the document.

This can be done using `block=tbs:page`, or `block=tbs:section` since you've defined correctly the page break or the section. The OpenTBS package gives a DOCX template as demo which show how to merge with pages.

Since you have merged one invoice per page, you can simple simply merge the dynamic order items using a sub-block ([more details here](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/manual.php#html_block_subblock)). There is an [inline demo](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=subblock&m=result) of sub-block.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I had been looking at the wrong place at your website to find the right answer! It looks a bit complicated though, but I will give it a try tomorrow.